# Execute test case 2 if test case 1 fails and so on with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have written few functions in my base page and I am trying to call it in my test. However, if  one of the functions fails, the test does not go further. How I can achieve this using selenium python so the test keeps running and give the errors later.

Comment: How many `test_*` functions do you have inside of your TestCase class?

Comment: Inside my test there are 6

Comment: Do all six test functions run if one of them fails?

Comment: not it does not. It stops if something fails

Comment: Would you mind updating your question to include the errors so we can understand where it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python unit testing using either `unittest.TestCase` classes or the `django.test.TestCase` classes, you should create one `test_*` function for each logical concept that you want to test. A unit test should fail for only one reason. It is ok to have multiple ways to test for the one reason but the test should fail for only one reason.

A test class may be as follows:

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver

class FooTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        [...]

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()
        [...]

    def test_thing_one(self):
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        self.assertIn('My Title', self.browser.title)

    def test_thing_two(self):
        [...]
        self.assertTrue(foobar)
```

In this class there are 2 `test_*` functions. When you run this test case and both pass you would see output similar to:

```
..
-------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.213s
```

It tells us it ran two tests. Notice that it also has two periods. One for each test. Period means test passed. Both passed. If the first test failed we would see:

```
F.
===============================
FAIL: test_thing_one (mytests.FooTestCase)
-------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
# stack trace here
AssertionError: (rest of error)
-------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.213s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

This time one of the periods has been replaced with the letter F. There is still one period which represents a test that passed. Notice that the F comes first. This means that `test_thing_one` ran first and failed and even though it failed `test_thing_two` still ran normally and passed.

In `test_thing_one` we could have used multiple assertions as follows:

```
def test_thing_one(self):
    [...]
    self.assertIn(x, bar_list)
    self.assertTrue(something)
    self.assertIsInstance(a, b)
```

Now if `assertTrue` fails test_thing_one will stop at the point and `assertIsInstance` will never be called. This is correct behavior. If you still want `assertIsInstance` to be called even if `assertTrue` fails then you should create a new `test_*` method and move `assertIsInstance` to that method.

In general you should have only one `assert*` per `test_*`. This will help you limit it to testing only one concept. If these three asserts are testing only one concept this is ok, as you will know where to go in your code to fix that one small thing. If `assertTrue` tests one piece of code and `assertIsInstance` tests another piece of code they should be in two separate `test_*` methods.

---

If you have 6 test cases and your are not seeing a combination of 6 periods or `F` then something else abnormal is happening. If that is the case please update your question with the errors so we can fix that problem.

Comment: nice unit testing advice, but I don't think it answers the OP's question.

Comment: @Chiragverma Did this actually help you and answer your question? Were your tests actually failing to complete or did this help you understand why they were failing part way through?

Comment: @Noah, I have posted the answer. Yes it did help me but I want to make sure this is the right approach

Comment: @Chiragverma Given that you unmarked this answer as accepted, I wondered if there was something from the answer that is missing. How can I help answer your question?

Comment: @Noah, I am sorry, but your answer helped. It got unmarked by mistake.

Comment: In my case, I am checking the web app, if the first test case fails, like the web page suppose to display the list of members and it couldn't. . Then the second test case is open the member using the list. This will also fails right. Just a doubt. Thats how my test cases are running.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following approach to achieve this. Is this the right approach?

```
class mytest(BaseTestCase, unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super(mytest, self).setUp()



    def test_one(self):
        # content


    def test_two(self):
        # content

    def test_three(self):
       # content

    def test_four(self):
        # content

    def test_five(self):
        # content

    def test_six(self):
        # content        


    def tearDown(self):
        super(mutest, self).tearDown()
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right idea. You do not need to call the superclass `setUp` or `tearDown` methods. The default implementation actually does nothing. And I'm not sure what `BaseTestCase` is. If that is one of your classes and you want to do multiple inheritance that is fine. Otherwise, you only need to extend `unittest.TestCase`. If using django you would extend `django.test.TestCase`.